# Problema al enviar datos al controlador desde jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Intento enviar un parámetro al controlador desde jquery utilizando una llamada ajax y por POST. Obtengo un error 500.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

El código de mi controlador es este:

```
[Authorize]
public class MiController: Controller
{
   ...
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetProvincias(int? id)
   {
       ...
       return Json(_miServicio.GetProvincias(id));
   }
}
```

Y el código jquery es este:

```
function CargarProvincias(param) {
   let ddlProvincias = $('#dll_Provincia');
   ddlProvincias.empty();
   ddlProvincias.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Seleccionar provincia</option>');
   ddlProvincias.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

   $.ajax({
      url: window._getProvinciasUrl,
      data: { id: param },
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (respuesta) {
      $.each(respuesta, function (index, datos) {
          ddlProvincias.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', datos.IdProv).text(datos.NomProvincia));
      });
     },
   });
  }
```

En las diferentes pruebas que he realizado he observado que:

- Si elimino el parámetro de la acción del controlador, funciona correctamente.
- Si en lugar de usar POST, utilizo GET, también funciona correctamente.

Por más ejemplos que miro, todos van así.
¿Qué se me escapa?

Comment: Has probado en la firma de `GetProvincias` a poner un parámetro no nullable? `public ActionResult GetProvincias(int id)`?

Comment: Sí. También lo he probado. De hecho es como lo tenía al principio porque ese parámetro siempre ha de venir informado.

Comment: Y la url supongo que es la correcta no? Que tiene `_getProvinciasUrl`?

Comment: La dirección de la acción. He comprobado que el contenido es correcto. Lo informo así porque al poner los scripts en un fichero .js independiente no puedo utilizar helpers, a diferencia de si lo hago directamente en la vista. En la vista tengo esto: window._getProvinciasUrl = '@Url.Action("GetProvincias", "MiController")';

Comment: Los errores 500 son en el código del servidor, es ahí donde debes mirar y no tanto en el código Javascript. Sería aclaratorio que mostrases el código de servidor que maneja la petición Ajax.

Comment: Cedano, tengo un breakpoint puesto en la acción y cuando me falla, ni tan siquiera se me detiene. Es como si no llegara a la acción, y como he comentado antes, si elimino el parámetro de la acción, funciona correctamente, con la salvedad de que me devuelve todas las provincias y no un subconjunto como yo quiero. (PD. no entiendo a que te refieres con el _código de servidor que maneja la petición Ajax_)

Comment: Otra prueba que se me ocurre...intenta pasar un numero fijo como parametro `data: { id: 1 },` por ejemplo, a ver si el error es el mismo

Comment: Pikoh, también lo probé. No es eso.

Comment: Creo que lo que pasa es que tu controlador es un GET y en el ajax estas poniendo POST, el type tendría que ser GET también así como [HttpGet]

Comment: Japh, si observas el código de mi controlador, verás que está decorado con [HttpPost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo como respuesta el comentario que me ha hecho Orlando.

Dejar el contenType como: `application/json; charset=utf-8`
y al parametro data pasarle el parametro asi: `JSON.stringify({ id: param })`

Comment: ContentType es el tipo de dato que espera recibir el servidor. Segun la [documentacion](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) el valor por defecto es: `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`.

Comment: No esta demas probar dejando el contenType como `'application/json; charset=utf-8'` y al parametro `data` pasarle el parametro asi: `JSON.stringify({ id: param })`

Comment: Orlando, efectivamente tu propuesta es buena, funciona correctamente al forzar la conversión del parámetro a una cadena JSON. Gracias